# Is there a Facebook IM client for Mint (or Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, pidgin, facebook

A few years ago pidgin worked fine, but now I can't find one IM client that connects on Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any XMPP client AFAIK(Facebook IM is XMPP based).
There is also an option of using non offical facebook messenger desktop version.
http://messengerfordesktop.com/

Can also try: Empathy, Kopete or Emesene.

EDIT: Pidgin works fine with facebook, make sure you have package: purple-facebook

Comment: Facebook stopped providing XMPP a few months ago.

Comment: http://messengerfordesktop.com/ works, but it don't stay on notitification area.